# Can't pass value from textbox to controller using textboxfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, textbox, controller, html.textboxfor

I try to pass values from textbox to controller but my first value gets passed and my second value doesn't get passed . To be short i'll post my code here :

The code from index view :

```
@model FirstProject.Controllers.Family

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("SubmitTextBox", "OtherExample", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Member.FirstName)
    <input type="submit"/>
}

<p>@Model.Name</p>
<p>@Model.Member.FirstName</p>
```

the code from controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new Family());
        }

        public ActionResult SubmitTextBox(Family model)
        {
            return View("Index", model);
        }
```

and my model :

```
public class Family
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Member Member;
    public Family()
    {
        Member = new Member();
    }

}

public class Member
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

My Name value is shown but my Member.Firstname is'n shown in the view because isn't passed. What is happening can someone explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not make `Member` **property**.

Make `Member` **property** in Model instead of field:

```
public Member Member {get;set;}
```

Your Model:

```
public class Family
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Member Member {get;set;}
    public Family()
    {
        Member = new Member();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, that was it. That was the problem. Now i have fixed it.

Comment: I remember being caught by this the first time I worked with MVC. And I've been sat here for half an hour trying to sort it out now. Than Ehsan.